# print statement with first character of square bracket not output

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

Having some strange results with sqlcmd in a new (for me) environment.  When using the print statement and the first character is a square bracket (ie [) it wont print.  My testing below.

> ```
> print "statement bug - square bracket as first character -  bit printed but     [test] missing"
> -- :r "test.print.sql"
> :out "test.print.txt"
>
> print "first character is [ with matching ]";
> print "[test]bit"   
> print "[test]bit";  
> print '[test]bit'   
> print '[test]bit';   
>
> print "first character is [ without matching ]";
> print "[test bit"   
> print "[test bit";  
> print '[test bit'   
> print '[test bit';   
>
> print "first character is [ without matching ] no text";
> print "["   
> print "[";  
> print '['   
> print '[';   
>
> print "first character is space = all ok";    
> print " [test]bit"   
> print " [test]bit";  
> print ' [test]bit'   
> print ' [test]bit';   
>
> print "last character is space ";
> print "[test]bit "   
> print "[test]bit ";  
> print '[test]bit '   
> print '[test]bit ';   
>
> print "()";
> print "(test)bit "   
> print "(test)bit ";  
> print '(test)bit '   
> print '(test)bit ';   
>
> print "{}";
> print "{test}bit "   
> print "{test}bit ";  
> print '{test}bit '   
> print '{test}bit ';   
>
> go
> :out stdout
> ```

output as follows:

```
statement bug - square bracket as first character -  bit printed but [test] missing
first character is [ with matching ]
bit
bit
bit
bit
first character is [ without matching ]
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server][test bit
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server][test bit
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server][test bit
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server][test bit
first character is [ without matching ] no text
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server][
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server][
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server][
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server][
first character is space = all ok
 [test]bit
 [test]bit
 [test]bit
 [test]bit
last character is space 
bit 
bit 
bit 
bit 
()
(test)bit 
(test)bit 
(test)bit 
(test)bit 
{}
{test}bit 
{test}bit 
{test}bit 
{test}bit
```

Same result under 2008R2 and 2012 (SP1).  And also directly firing the commands without the :run / :out to file wrapper.

Comment: How are you running this? How are you able to use `"` as string delimiter ? Isn't `'` the delimiter?

Comment: If I execute the following - `print '[test]bit'` from SQL Server New Query window, it prints `[test]bit` as result.

Comment: @ArunGeorge running via cmd.  Thats why I tried the ' delimiter.  Normally using " delimiter.

Comment: Decided to lodge a bug request and noticed this [disclaimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility) in yellow on the sqlcmd utility page, though the print command is not part of ssms sqlcmd mode.

Comment: I had same problem. Tried to generate .ini file. Luckily `print ' [xxx]'` works and some parsers support ini section starting with space.